# Merge Two Lists in two directions

Tags: java, list, arraylist, merge

What is the efficient way to merge two lists in two directions, one in incremented way and other in decremented way. Both lists are not of the same length.

```
List1 = ["eight", "nine"] // first element "eight" should be the starting point
List2 = ["three", "six", "seven", "eight"] // last element "eight" should be the starting point
```

So the final result would be

```
c= ["eight", "eight", "nine", "seven", "six", "three"]
```

This is not exactly my code, but this is an example. Here all lists are considered from `first-element` of each list. But I need one should be from `first-element` to `last-element` while other from the `last-element` to `first-element`

```
List<String> a = [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ];
List<String> b = [ "fee", "fi" ];
List<String> c = [ "broccoli", "tomato", "potato" ];
List<String> d = [ "purple" ];

Iterator<String> interleaved = Iterators.interleave( 
    a.iterator(), b.iterator(),
    c.iterator(), d.iterator() );
int count = 1;
while ( interleaved.hasNext() ) {
   System.out.println( count++ + ": " + interleaved.next() );
}

Output:

1: one
2: fee
3: broccoli
4: purple
5: two
6: fi
7: tomato
8: three
9: potato
10: four
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: can u clear ur question little bit?

Comment: Is it clear now @Mr.Robot ?

Comment: So, you almost have what you want, but simply want some of the iterators to iterate in reverse, without calling [`Collections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29), it that it?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah and `Iterators.interleave` `guava` is not recognized, although guava is added.

Comment: I don't think `Iterators.interleave()` has been implemented yet. You have to implement that one yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a use of `Collections` as follows:

```
String[] a = ...;
String[] b = ...;
ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(firstList, a);
Collections.addAll(secondList, b);
Collections.reverse(secondList);
firstList.addAll(secondList);
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are ArrayList not arrays

Comment: then it's even easier since you already have two lists so you could proceed right away to 'reverse()' line

Answer (score 0):

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has a [`listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28int%29) method that returns a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which can be iterated backwards by calling [`previous()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous%28%29), so you could create your own class implementing [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) that wraps another `ListIterator`, reversing the iteration order, i.e. [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next%28%29) calls `previous()` and vice versa.